# JAVA - Encontrar nombres de identificadores repetidos por medio de pilas

Tags: java, pilas

1. Hace poco me dejaron un ejercicio en el que, por
   medio de pilas, tengo que encontrar y no aceptar en la misma pila a
   aquellos identificadores que ya existan. He estado unos días
   intentándolo hacer, pero no obtengo los resultados que quiero. El
   programa debe validar identificadores de tipo `double`, `int` y `String`.
   Ejemplo:

```
     int numero; 
     String palabras; 
     double numero;
```

El programa
    deberá rechazar el identificador **numero** de tipo `double`, puesto que
    ya hay un identificador con el mismo nombre. El código es el
    siguiente:

> Clase Nodo:

```
public class Nodo {
    private String dato;
    private Nodo sig;
    public Nodo() {
        dato = "";
        sig = null;
    }

    public void gDato(String d) {
        this.dato = d;
    }

    public void gSig(Nodo n) {
        this.sig = n;
    }

    public String mdato() {
        return this.dato;
    }

    public Nodo msig() {
        return this.sig;
    }
}
```

> Clase Pila:

```
public class Pila {
    private Nodo inicio;
    public Pila() {
        this.inicio = null;
    }

    public boolean vacia() {
        return inicio == null;
    }

    public void insertar(Nodo nuevo) {
        if (vacia()) {
            this.inicio = nuevo;
        } else {
            Nodo aux = inicio;
            while (aux.msig() != null) {
                aux = aux.msig();
            }
            aux.gSig(nuevo);
        }
    }

    public boolean buscar(String d) {
        if (vacia()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            Nodo aux = inicio;
            do {
                if (aux.mdato() == d) {
                return true;
                } else {
                    aux = aux.msig();
                }

            } while (aux.msig() != null);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Es decir, si en la pila tengo los nombres David, Pepito, no se podrá ingresar otra vez pepito porque ya existe en la pila y deberá mandar algún mensaje de error. Así mismo sería con números enteros, si en la pila tengo los números 1, 2, 5, al momento de insertar el 2, debería detectarlo y mandar algún error porque el número 2 ya existe en la pila. Eso es lo que quieres?

Comment: La pila solamente debe aceptar cadenas, como el ejemplo de los nombres que pusiste. La pila no debe aceptar cadenas que ya existan dentro de la misma. El proceso no se hace con números.

Comment: Entonces que significa esto: ***El programa debe validar identificadores de tipo double, int y String***...

Comment: Que después de **int**,**double** o **String** va un identificador. Por ejemplo: int Pepito, double David, String Pepito. No debería de aceptar el **String Pepito** debido a que **Pepito** ya está ocupado en el **int**. La pila debe guardar cadenas desde el tipo de dato, hasta el identificador, pero únicamente verifica el nuevo identificador introducido no esté dentro de la pila, en caso de estar, mandar mensaje de error.

Comment: Para lograr que no se inserten nombres repetidos, simplemente añade una validación en el método de insertar, en la cual, recorra la pila (a través de un bucle) y que busque si el nombre existe (a través de una condicional).